# Missing argument for parameter #1 in call error for function with no params. Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6-beta6

I am using xcode 6 beta 6 and I get this weird error for a function that has no params.

Here is the function

```
func allStudents ()-> [String]{
    var appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
    var context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
    var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Student")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    //Set error to nil for now
    //TODO: Give an actual error.
    var result:NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)

    var students:[String]!
    for child in result{
        var fullname:String = child.valueForKey("firstName") as String + " "
        fullname += child.valueForKey("middleName") as String + " "
        fullname += child.valueForKey("lastName") as String
        students.append(fullname)
    }


    return students
}
```

and here is the call

```
var all = StudentList.allStudents()
```

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: What is `StudentList`?  Is it your class or is it a variable (in which case it should have a lower case s - `studentList`)

Comment: Are you sure that's the line it's crashing on? A simple version of this in playground works fine.  ALthough you do have one obvious error: `var students:[String]!` never gets a value, it's initialized to `nil`. You probably want `var students:[String] = []`.

Comment: Its not an error from the program crashing its xcode telling me its wrong. And yes StudentList is my class.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Assuming `StudentList` is a class, i.e.

```
class StudentList {

    func allStudents ()-> [String]{
      ....
    }
}
```

Then an expression like this

```
var all = StudentList.allStudents()
```

will throw the said exception, because `allStudents` is applied to a class instead of an instance of the class. The `allStudents` function is expecting a `self` parameter (a reference to the  instance). It explains the error message.

This will be resolved if you do

```
var all = StudentList().allStudents()
```

Comment: or it need to be class/static method

Answer (score 13):

Swift has Instance Methods and Type Methods. An instance method is a method that is called from a particular instance of a class. A Type Method is a static method that is called from the class itself.

## Instance Methods

An instance method would look something like this:

```
class StudentList {

    func allStudents() -> [String] {
      ....
    }
}
```

In order for the `allStudents` method to be called, the `StudentsList` class needs to be initialized first.

```
let list = StudentsList() // initialize the class
let all = list.allStudents() // call a method on the class instance
```

Trying to call an instance method on the class itself gives an error.

## Type Methods

[Type Methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html) are static methods that belong to the class, not an instance of the class. As was alluded to in the comments to @AnthodyKong's answer, a Type Method can be created by using the `class` or `static` keywords before `func`. Classes are passed by reference and Structs are passed by value, so these are known as reference type and value type. Here are what they would look like:

**Reference Type**

```
class StudentList {

    class func allStudents() -> [String] {
      ....
    }
}
```

**Value Type**

```
struct StudentList {

    static func allStudents() -> [String] {
      ....
    }
}
```

**Call with**

```
let all = StudentList.allStudents()
```

Because `allStudents` is a Type Method, the class (or struct) doesn't need to be initialized first.

**See also**

- [Method documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html)
- [Instance Methods and Type Methods in Swift](http://www.codingexplorer.com/instance-methods-and-type-methods-in-swift/)

Comment: This is great but they really need to update the text of the warning that you get. Why doesn't it just *say* that the function should be a class function and offer to fix it for you...?

Comment: Indeed. If someone ever invents a programming language that gives intelligent error messages, I'm learning it.

Comment: How about we write an API for clang where, before it shows you an error message, first it searches stack overflow and uses a machine learning algorithm to find the most likely solution to the problem, then just provides you a link to the question :D