# swift: Call function in scene from controller

Tags: ios, function, swift

I'm trying to rotate a SKSpriteNode based on pan gesture. I figured out the only way to detect pan is to insert small code in the GameViewController.swift. To rotate the sprite on pan, I must call for a rotate function in my scene file. I tried doing `PlayScene.rotateTommyLeft()` but it gives me error saying `Missing argument for parameter #1 in call` which is weird cause the function rotateTommyLeft shouldn't require a parameter. I'm posting it below.

```
func rotateTommyLeft()
{
    tommy.zRotation--
}
```

Comment: Probably you declared `rotateTommyLeft` twice? (And you meant `rotateTommyRight`the second time?)

Comment: Nope. Thats not the case. However, I do seem to notice some strange parameter input required when typing the function. I took a screenshot.

[link](http://i.imgur.com/CQ8Xk4u.png)

Comment: Looks like the method is recognized as function. Did you tried cleaning and rebuilding?

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't do anything. The projects cleans but I get the same error when rebuilding.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Missing argument for parameter #1 in call error for function with no params. Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25435928/missing-argument-for-parameter-1-in-call-error-for-function-with-no-params-swi)

Comment: Thank you for your help and the question is solved now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because you are calling

```
PlayScene.rotateTommyLeft()
```

where `PlayScene` is a class, not an instance

See a similar question and answer here: [Missing argument for parameter #1 in call error for function with no params. Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25435928/missing-argument-for-parameter-1-in-call-error-for-function-with-no-params-swi/25438320#25438320)

Comment: Thank you for answering me. To clarify, I changed `PlayScene.rotateTommyLeft()` to `PlayScene().rotateTommyLeft()` and it started working.